# Querying data under same attribute in SPARQL

Tags: rdf, sparql

I have RDF data like this:(Updated, the full file)

The source I got this RDF is: http://reach.suny.edu/display/Hajagos_Janos
When you the button of "paper clip" under the profile picture, you can download this file.
And the SPARQL endpoints was: http://link.informatics.stonybrook.edu/sparql/

```xml
    <rdf:RDF
    xmlns:geo="http://aims.fao.org/aos/geopolitical.owl#"
    xmlns:c4o="http://purl.org/spar/c4o/"
    xmlns:vitro-public="http://vitro.mannlib.cornell.edu/ns/vitro/public#"
    xmlns:skos="http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#"
    xmlns:ero="http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/"
    xmlns:event="http://purl.org/NET/c4dm/event.owl#"
    xmlns:pvs="http://vivoweb.org/ontology/provenance-support#"
    xmlns:dcelem="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
    xmlns:j.0="http://reach.suny.edu/ns#"
    xmlns:vivo="http://vivoweb.org/ontology/core#"
    xmlns:vitro="http://vitro.mannlib.cornell.edu/ns/vitro/0.7#"
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:bibo="http://purl.org/ontology/bibo/"
    xmlns:foaf="http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/"
    xmlns:reach="http://reach.suny.edu/ontology/core#"
    xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
    xmlns:dcterms="http://purl.org/dc/terms/"
    xmlns:scires="http://vivoweb.org/ontology/scientific-research#"
    xmlns:fabio="http://purl.org/spar/fabio/"
    xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#" > 
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://reach.suny.edu/individual/n2406">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Thing"/>
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://vivoweb.org/ontology/core#DateTimeInterval"/>
    <vivo:start rdf:resource="http://reach.suny.edu/individual/n10121"/>
    <vivo:end rdf:resource="http://reach.suny.edu/individual/n3729"/>
  </rdf:Description>
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://reach.suny.edu/individual/n6042">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Thing"/>
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://vivoweb.org/ontology/core#Role"/>
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://vivoweb.org/ontology/core#PresenterRole"/>
    <vivo:roleRealizedIn rdf:resource="http://reach.suny.edu/individual/n3694"/>
    <vivo:dateTimeInterval rdf:resource="http://reach.suny.edu/individual/n2406"/>
    <vivo:presenterRoleOf rdf:resource="http://reach.suny.edu/individual/Hajagos_Janos"/>
    <rdfs:label rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Speaker</rdfs:label>
  </rdf:Description>
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://reach.suny.edu/individual/n3694">
    <rdfs:label rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">VIVO Mini-Grant: Integrating the UMLS Ontology into VIVO for Linking Biomedical Scientists</rdfs:label>
  </rdf:Description>
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://reach.suny.edu/individual/n4507">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Thing"/>
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://vivoweb.org/ontology/core#Position"/>
    <vivo:positionForPerson rdf:resource="http://reach.suny.edu/individual/Hajagos_Janos"/>
    <vivo:positionInOrganization rdf:resource="http://reach.suny.edu/individual/n4644"/>
    <vivo:rank rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#int">1</vivo:rank>
    <rdfs:label rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Clinical Assistant Professor</rdfs:label>
  </rdf:Description>
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://reach.suny.edu/individual/n5408">
    <rdfs:label>Semantic Web</rdfs:label>
  </rdf:Description>
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://link.informatics.stonybrook.edu/umls/CUI/C0025088">
    <rdfs:label rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Medical Informatics</rdfs:label>
  </rdf:Description>
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://vivoweb.org/ontology/core#yearPrecision">
    <rdfs:label xml:lang="en-US">yearPrecision</rdfs:label>
  </rdf:Description>
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://reach.suny.edu/individual/n4542">
    <rdfs:label rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Medical Informatics</rdfs:label>
  </rdf:Description>
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://reach.suny.edu/individual/a21575203">
    <rdfs:label>Linked open drug data for pharmaceutical research and development.</rdfs:label>
  </rdf:Description>
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://link.informatics.stonybrook.edu/umls/CUI/C0010992">
    <rdfs:label rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Data Analysis</rdfs:label>
  </rdf:Description>
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://link.informatics.stonybrook.edu/umls/CUI/C0085567">
    <rdfs:label rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">UMLS</rdfs:label>
  </rdf:Description>
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://reach.suny.edu/individual/n10121">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Thing"/>
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://vivoweb.org/ontology/core#DateTimeValue"/>
    <vivo:dateTimePrecision rdf:resource="http://vivoweb.org/ontology/core#yearPrecision"/>
    <vivo:dateTime rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime">2011-01-01T00:00:00</vivo:dateTime>
  </rdf:Description>
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://reach.suny.edu/individual/n4418">
    <rdfs:label xml:lang="en-US">Semantic Web Architecture Group</rdfs:label>
  </rdf:Description>
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://link.informatics.stonybrook.edu/umls/CUI/C0025071">
    <rdfs:label rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Medicaid</rdfs:label>
  </rdf:Description>
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://link.informatics.stonybrook.edu/umls/CUI/C1882937">
    <rdfs:label rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">RDF</rdfs:label>
  </rdf:Description>
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://reach.suny.edu/individual/gHajagos_Janos_21575203">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Thing"/>
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://vivoweb.org/ontology/core#Relationship"/>
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://vivoweb.org/ontology/core#Authorship"/>
    <vivo:linkedAuthor rdf:resource="http://reach.suny.edu/individual/Hajagos_Janos"/>
    <vivo:linkedInformationResource rdf:resource="http://reach.suny.edu/individual/a21575203"/>
  </rdf:Description>
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://reach.suny.edu/individual/n6907">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Thing"/>
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://vivoweb.org/ontology/core#Position"/>
    <vivo:positionForPerson rdf:resource="http://reach.suny.edu/individual/Hajagos_Janos"/>
    <vivo:positionInOrganization rdf:resource="http://reach.suny.edu/individual/n4542"/>
    <vivo:rank rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#int">2</vivo:rank>
    <rdfs:label rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Senior Programmer/Data Analyst</rdfs:label>
  </rdf:Description>
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://reach.suny.edu/individual/n2444">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Thing"/>
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://vivoweb.org/ontology/core#Role"/>
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://vivoweb.org/ontology/core#MemberRole"/>
    <vivo:memberRoleOf rdf:resource="http://reach.suny.edu/individual/Hajagos_Janos"/>
    <vivo:roleContributesTo rdf:resource="http://reach.suny.edu/individual/n4418"/>
  </rdf:Description>
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://reach.suny.edu/individual/n3729">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Thing"/>
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://vivoweb.org/ontology/core#DateTimeValue"/>
    <vivo:dateTimePrecision rdf:resource="http://vivoweb.org/ontology/core#yearPrecision"/>
    <vivo:dateTime rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime">2011-01-01T00:00:00</vivo:dateTime>
  </rdf:Description>
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://link.informatics.stonybrook.edu/umls/CUI/C0034379">
    <rdfs:label rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Health care quality</rdfs:label>
  </rdf:Description>
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://reach.suny.edu/individual/Hajagos_Janos">
    <foaf:lastName rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Hajagos</foaf:lastName>
    <vivo:personInPosition rdf:resource="http://reach.suny.edu/individual/n4507"/>
    <vivo:educationalTraining rdf:resource="http://reach.suny.edu/individual/n20726"/>
    <vivo:authorInAuthorship rdf:resource="http://reach.suny.edu/individual/gHajagos_Janos_21575203"/>
    <vivo:hasResearchArea rdf:resource="http://link.informatics.stonybrook.edu/umls/CUI/C0010992"/>
    <vivo:hasResearchArea rdf:resource="http://link.informatics.stonybrook.edu/umls/CUI/C1882937"/>
    <vivo:personInPosition rdf:resource="http://reach.suny.edu/individual/n6907"/>
    <vivo:faxNumber>631-444-8873</vivo:faxNumber>
    <j.0:networkId>jhajagos</j.0:networkId>
    <vivo:hasMemberRole rdf:resource="http://reach.suny.edu/individual/n2444"/>
    <vivo:hasPresenterRole rdf:resource="http://reach.suny.edu/individual/n6042"/>
    <vivo:middleName>G</vivo:middleName>
    <vitro-public:mainImage rdf:resource="http://reach.suny.edu/individual/n1206"/>
    <vivo:email>risk.limits@gmail.com</vivo:email>
    <vivo:hasResearchArea rdf:resource="http://link.informatics.stonybrook.edu/umls/CUI/C0025071"/>
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://reach.suny.edu/ontology/core#SUNY_REACH_Investigator"/>
    <vivo:hasResearchArea rdf:resource="http://link.informatics.stonybrook.edu/umls/CUI/C0085567"/>
    <rdfs:label xml:lang="en-US">Hajagos, Janos</rdfs:label>
    <foaf:firstName rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Janos</foaf:firstName>
    <vivo:phoneNumber>631-444-1596</vivo:phoneNumber>
    <vivo:hasResearchArea rdf:resource="http://link.informatics.stonybrook.edu/umls/CUI/C0034379"/>
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/Person"/>
    <vivo:hasResearchArea rdf:resource="http://reach.suny.edu/individual/n5408"/>
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/Agent"/>
    <vivo:preferredTitle>Senior Programmer/Analyst&lt;br /&gt;</vivo:preferredTitle>
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Thing"/>
    <vivo:primaryEmail>janos.hajagos@stonybrook.edu</vivo:primaryEmail>
    <bibo:suffixName>Ph.D.</bibo:suffixName>
    <vivo:hasResearchArea rdf:resource="http://link.informatics.stonybrook.edu/umls/CUI/C0025088"/>
  </rdf:Description>
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://reach.suny.edu/individual/n4644">
    <rdfs:label rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">BS/HS Program</rdfs:label>
  </rdf:Description>
</rdf:RDF>
```

I want to find the publications of a person whose last name is `"Hajagos"`. From the data, we can see it's under `<rdfs:label> "Linked open drug data for pharmaceutical research and development"`. But there are also many values under the same `<rdfs:label>`.  How could I query for this. I tried the following SPARQL, but got nothing useful:

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
PREFIX vivo: <http://vivoweb.org/ontology/core#>

SELECT ?publication
WHERE {
  ?person foaf:lastName "Hajagos" .
  ?person rdfs:label ?publication
}
```

By this query I can only get `en-US`, which is also a value of the attribute `<rdfs:label>`.

Comment: That data isn't complete RDF/XML;  can you provide a complete RDF document that we can work against?

Comment: Hi Taylor thanks for so patient replies. I just updated the full rdf file, and added the link of SPARQL endpoint. I'll try your solution after class and see whether it works.. Thanks..

Comment: Actually only RDF/xml data is provided. Do I need to manually convert it to turtle/ntriples?

Comment: You don't need to convert it;  they're both valid serializations of RDF.  One is just much more _human_-readable, and it's much easier to write a query when the data is in a human readable form, since it's easier to see what's there.  Where is the data coming from though?  I thought (from previous questions) that you were querying against a Virtuoso endpoint, and I'd expect it to be able to provide results in a number of formats.  It's not a big deal, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you take your data and convert it to a more human readable format such as Turtle, it's easier to see the connections in your data.  In particular, after converting it, we get the following description of the author we're concerned with:

```
<http://reach.suny.edu/individual/Hajagos_Janos>
        a                         reach:SUNY_REACH_Investigator , foaf:Person , foaf:Agent , owl:Thing ;
        rdfs:label                "Hajagos, Janos"@en-US ;
        bibo:suffixName           "Ph.D." ;
        j.0:networkId             "jhajagos" ;
        vitro-public:mainImage    <http://reach.suny.edu/individual/n1206> ;
        vivo:authorInAuthorship   <http://reach.suny.edu/individual/gHajagos_Janos_21575203> ;
        vivo:educationalTraining  <http://reach.suny.edu/individual/n20726> ;
        vivo:email                "risk.limits@gmail.com" ;
        vivo:faxNumber            "631-444-8873" ;
        vivo:hasMemberRole        <http://reach.suny.edu/individual/n2444> ;
        vivo:hasPresenterRole     <http://reach.suny.edu/individual/n6042> ;
        vivo:hasResearchArea      <http://link.informatics.stonybrook.edu/umls/CUI/C0010992> , <http://link.informatics.stonybrook.edu/umls/CUI/C1882937> , <http://link.informatics.stonybrook.edu/umls/CUI/C0025071> , <http://link.informatics.stonybrook.edu/umls/CUI/C0085567> , <http://link.informatics.stonybrook.edu/umls/CUI/C0034379> , <http://reach.suny.edu/individual/n5408> , <http://link.informatics.stonybrook.edu/umls/CUI/C0025088> ;
        vivo:middleName           "G" ;
        vivo:personInPosition     <http://reach.suny.edu/individual/n4507> , <http://reach.suny.edu/individual/n6907> ;
        vivo:phoneNumber          "631-444-1596" ;
        vivo:preferredTitle       "Senior Programmer/Analyst<br />" ;
        vivo:primaryEmail         "janos.hajagos@stonybrook.edu" ;
        foaf:firstName            "Janos"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string> ;
        foaf:lastName             "Hajagos"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string> .
```

There's not a whole lot in there that relates to authorship, but there is the predicate and object:

```
vivo:authorInAuthorship   <http://reach.suny.edu/individual/gHajagos_Janos_21575203> ;
```

If we follow that object, we see:

```
<http://reach.suny.edu/individual/gHajagos_Janos_21575203>
        a                               owl:Thing , vivo:Relationship , vivo:Authorship ;
        vivo:linkedAuthor               <http://reach.suny.edu/individual/Hajagos_Janos> ;
        vivo:linkedInformationResource  <http://reach.suny.edu/individual/a21575203> .
```

and it's probably that linked information resource, `<http://reach.suny.edu/individual/a21575203>`, that we're interested in.  There's not a lot of information about, but there's

```
<http://reach.suny.edu/individual/a21575203>
        rdfs:label  "Linked open drug data for pharmaceutical research and development." .
```

Based on this structure, we can write a query that finds `vivo:Authorship`s and their `vivo:linkedAuthor`s, as well as the `rdfs:label`s of any `vivo:linkedInformationResource`s.  To query specifically for `"Hajagos"`, you can use:

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
PREFIX vivo: <http://vivoweb.org/ontology/core#>

SELECT ?label
WHERE {
  ?authorship vivo:linkedAuthor ?author ;
              vivo:linkedInformationResource ?resource .
  ?author foaf:lastName "Hajagos" .
  ?resource rdfs:label ?label .
}
```

To get more general results (and also cleaning up the query a bit), you could use:

```
prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
prefix foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
prefix vivo: <http://vivoweb.org/ontology/core#>

select ?lastName ?label where {
  ?authorship vivo:linkedAuthor [ foaf:lastName ?lastName ] ;
              vivo:linkedInformationResource [ rdfs:label ?label ] .
}
```

[SPARQL results](http://link.informatics.stonybrook.edu/sparql/?default-graph-uri=&query=%0D%0Aprefix%20rdfs%3a%20%3Chttp://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#%3E%0D%0Aprefix%20foaf%3a%20%3Chttp://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/%3E%0D%0Aprefix%20vivo%3a%20%3Chttp://vivoweb.org/ontology/core#%3E%0D%0A%0D%0Aselect%20?lastName%20?label%20where%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20?authorship%20vivo%3alinkedAuthor%20%5B%20foaf%3alastName%20?lastName%20%5D%20;%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20vivo%3alinkedInformationResource%20%5B%20rdfs%3alabel%20?label%20%5D%20.%0D%0A%7D&format=text/html&timeout=0&debug=on)

which produces results like this with your data;

```
$ sparql --data data2.n3 --query query.rq
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| lastName                                             | label                                                                |
===============================================================================================================================
| "Hajagos"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string> | "Linked open drug data for pharmaceutical research and development." |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

and lots of results when run at the endpoint.  That said, I don't see any results for Hajagos in the results from the endpoint.  I don't know why this is (but some considerations follow in the next section).

### Caveats

After some experimentation, it seems like there are some caveats.  For instance, if we search for triples with the object `"Hajagos"`, we get different triples than if we search for `"Hajagos"^^xsd:string`.  For instance, this query

```
select ?s ?p { ?s ?p "Hajagos" }
```

returns

```
s                                          p
http://reach.suny.edu/individual/Hajagos_J http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/lastName
```

but this query

```
select ?s ?p { ?s ?p "Hajagos"^^xsd:string }
```

returns

```
s                                              p
http://reach.suny.edu/individual/Hajagos_Janos http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/lastName
```

Notice that the individuals are different!  This is not a great state of affairs.  We can query for both, but

```
select ?s ?p { 
  { ?s ?p "Hajagos" } UNION { ?s ?p "Hajagos"^^xsd:string }
}
```

finds

```
s                                              p
http://reach.suny.edu/individual/Hajagos_J     http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/lastName
http://reach.suny.edu/individual/Hajagos_Janos http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/lastName
```

Comment: Thanks Joshua, but I tried to run your second to last query(that Hajagos one) in the endpoint: http://link.informatics.stonybrook.edu/sparql/, but I got nothing. Is there sth wrong with the endpoint, or the person "Hajagos" is not registered at foaf?

Comment: @YuchunCui I've included a link to the results of the second query when run against the endpoint.  I get lots of results, but the Hajagos results aren't among them.  I've included some thoughts about why this might be, but I'm not sure what the solution is yet…

Comment: I'm also considering your question Joshua, is it because "Janos Hajagos", this person isn't registered on foaf so that we can not get him by filtering with his last name?

Comment: @YuchunCui I don't know what you mean by "registered on foaf".  There's no central or authoritative repository of foaf data.  Foaf is just a vocabulary that people can use (or not).  It appears the problem here is that the values `"Hajagos"` (without a datatype) and `"Hajagos"^^xsd:string` are different, and that the endpoint doesn't contain all of the information (at least at the time that we executed those queries) that the downloadable profile does.  I don't know you'd work around that, except, perhaps, by crawling some of the pages and collecting the data yourself.